# How to find Maclaurin expansion given 2 terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion, proof-explanation

> Given function $f(x)$ defined for all $x$ we have:
>   $$
> f^{(2n)}(0)=0\\
> f^{(2n+1)}(0)=\frac{(2n)!}{n!}
> $$
>   Find Maclaurin series expansion for the function.

I came across this problem in my course and I don't understand the solution which goes as follows:
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{f^{(k)}(0)\cdot x^k}{k!}\stackrel{(1)}{=}\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{f^{(2k+1)}(0)\cdot x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\stackrel{(2)}{=}\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{(2k)!\cdot x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!k!}=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)k!}
$$
Specifically, I don't get the first and 2nd transition. I suppose that the 2nd transition has to do with fact that $f^{(2n+1)}(0)=\frac{(2n)!}{n!}$ but it's just one term of the series so why are we equating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are given that:
$$f^{(2n)}(0)=0\mbox{ and }f^{(2n+1)}(0)=\frac{(2n)!}{n!}\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$
So, shall we write it - let $k=n$:
$$f^{(2k)}(0)=0\mbox{ and }f^{(2k+1)}(0)=\frac{(2k)!}{k!}\ \forall k\in\mathbb{N}$$
We have just "renamed" $n$ to $k$. Now, we have, since all even terms of the MacLaurin series expansion of $f$ are zero:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{f^{k}(0)}{k!}x^k\overset{\text{all even terms}}{\underset{\text{are zero}}{=}}\sum_{k\text{ is odd}}\frac{f^{k}(0)}{k!}x^k\overset{k=2m+1}{=}\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{f^{2m+1}(0)}{(2m+1)!}x^{2m+1}\overset{(2)}{=}\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2m+1)m!}x^{2m+1}$$

So, to sum up, the key is that that given equalities hold for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Moreover, $k,n,m$ are just indices that "run" throughout the natural numbers or the odd natural numbers etc. I could write "whatever" instead of $m$, which would make no difference to what I would mean.

Comment: I didn't realize that $f^{(2n)}$ stands for even terms while $f^{(2n+1)}$ stands for odd ones, I thought the meaning was $2n$'th terms and $2n+1$'th term respectively, thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: No problem! :) Have a nice mathematical day!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand where your doubt is. And what do you mean when you write that “it's just one term”? You are assuming that$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}):f^{(2n+1)}(0)=\frac{(2n)!}{n!}$$and then you apply this assumption. That's all!

Answer (score 0):

You have a formula for $f(x)$. Differentiating, gives
$$f'(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2k}}{k!}.$$
You should be able to identify this.

Your step 1 is notationally bad; $k$ is used in a different role on the
two sides. I would write
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f^{(n)}(0)\frac{x^n}{n!}
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty f^{(2k+1)}(0)\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}.$$
The point is that the terms for even $n$ are zero, so we can forget those
and take $n=2k+1$ which accounts for the odd $n$ terms.